# Where to put UITableViewDelegate and DataSource in MVC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In terms of MVC, I have a UITableView that is instantiated in my controller and a model object that acts as a UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource. When I came to setting the delegate and datasource I just added both to point to the model:

```
    // INSIDE CONTROLLER
[tableView setDelegate:dataModel];
[tableView setDataSource:dataModel];
```

The DataSource fits in the model, that feels right. But the delegate, is that best in the model (so its with the DataSource) or would that (in MVC terms) fit better in the controller?

```
    // INSIDE CONTROLLER
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:dataModel];
```

**EDIT:** *I should clarify that my model objects contains an NSMutableArray that holds the data I wish to display in the UITableView (hence my setting the DataSource to the model). This seems to work well as I can populate the UITableView directly from the model.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual practice is to make your view controller the delegate and datasource, having it conform to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource or having it be a subclass of UITableViewController (which, you will note, conforms to those protocols itself).  Of course, the code that provides your controller with the actual data should remain in your model layer.

In response to your EDIT, your model class could expose the NSMutableArray as a property, which could easily be accessed by your table's view controller.

Comment: Much appreciated GriffeyDog, exactly what I was after, I will move both the "Delegate" and the "DataSource" into the controller. Also with regard to the edit, I already had a @property setup for the array and a pointer to the model setup in my controller, so absolutely, I should be accessing the array from the controller. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation seems to describe the table view delegate in terms of helping with view layout and the like. Unfortunately, there is a bit of conflation between the two in practice, such as the delegate returning dynamic row height (even though the data source returns the cells), or the delegate returning section header and footer views (even though the data source can just return plain titles).

Issues like this make it hard to cleanly separate the table view (which you need in order to call `reloadData`) from its data source and the data source from the delegate. When at all possible, it really is easiest if the same object functions as the data source *and* the delegate. When not possible, the delegate usually makes the most sense as the view controller managing the presentation of the table view.

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewDelegate is responsible for more GUI-oriented stuff, so your view controller, which contains the table view is the best candidate to be a view delegate, data source can not be related to a GUI, but usually and in all apple examples they bind the controller, that contains the table view as both, so in case of apple samples it looks like (from the table view controller or in IB):
YourTableViewController.m

```
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
```